# What type of thoughts are negative?and can these negative thoughts control our mind?

Tags: karma

Evil thoughts can destroy a person's well being

Comment: Dharma is will of Shriman Narayana if you violate it then its Adharma and that is what negative action is, so the thoughts that create negative actions are negative thoughts.

Comment: Any example?can you pls elaborate?

Comment: "aShtAdaza purANESu vyAsasya vacana dwayam | parOpakAraH puNyAya pApAyaH parapIDanam || "  Meaning: Vyasa iterates essentially two sentences in all the 18 puranas - benevolence (helping others) is virtue; harming others is sin.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Where is that verse from?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan just a popular saying

Comment: @moonstar2001 Oh ok, it's a nice verse.  I may post a question to find out who composed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hindu Shastras has identified primarily six inner foes of mankind. They are collectively called the [Arishadvargas or Shadaripus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadripu)

They are kAma (lust), krodha (anger), lobha (greed), moha (delusion), mada (arrogance) and mAtsarya (jealousy).

All the evil  thoughts that arise in our minds are triggered by one or more of the above 6 foes.

For example from lust arises illicit thoughts about sexual gratification, from anger arises the evil thoughts of destruction and revenge, from greed arises the desire of owning things illegally etc.

In Vedas there is a  mantra that symbolically identifies these 6 foes as six relevant animals. It also asks Lord Indra (the king of Gods) to kill them all for us.

> UlukayAtum shushulukayAtum jahi shvayAtum uta kokayAtum suparnayAtum
>   uta grdhrayAtum drshadeva pra mrina raksha indra.
>
> .............
>
> O Indra, kill the delusion (identified as the owl), anger (wolf),
>   jealousy (dog), the lust (chakravAka, a kind of bird), arrogance
>   (eagle) and the greed (vulture).
>
> **Atharva Veda Samhita 8.4.22**

In Sanskrit literature the chakrvAka bird is often described as being stricken with love and lust. So, its being associated in the mantra with lust or kama.

For dog we have a popular saying which says

> " dog neither eats the grass nor allows the cow to eat the grass in
>   the manger."

The dog is associated with jealousy or matsarya in the mantra.

Vulture can mean " a person of rapacious and predatory nature." Vulture is associated with arrogance and so on.

Basically, any thoughts that can be traced back to anyone of these aforementioned six foes of mind is detrimental to our spiritual progress and hence can be marked as "evil".

So, we have to monitor them and try to put a check on them. But obviously that is easier said than done.